# Concatenating Entire Row to Get Checksum of the Data Returns Error

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, dbeaver, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to concatenate an entire row of data to get their checksum output in AWS Redshift external tables to insert them in another external table.

Here's a sample of my code (I have much more columns around 24):

```
INSERT  INTO EXTERNAL_TABLE_4
SELECT  DISTINCT
        A.CD,
        B.TITLE,
        C.COUNTRY,
        A.CREATE_DT,
        CAST(CHECKSUM(
            COALESCE(CAST(A.CD AS VARCHAR(50)), '0') ||
            COALESCE(B.TITLE, '0') ||
            COALESCE(C.COUNTRY, '0') ||
            COALESCE(CAST(A.CREATE_DT AS VARCHAR(50)), '0')
        ) AS VARCHAR(256))
FROM    EXTERNAL_TABLE_1 A
        LEFT JOIN  EXTERNAL_TABLE_2    B   ON B.CD = A.CD
        LEFT JOIN  EXTERNAL_TABLE_3    C   ON C.CD = A.CD;
```

This format returns the following error on DBeaver:

```
SQL Error [42725]: ERROR: function checksum(text) is not unique
  Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

And returns the following error on Athena:

```
TYPE_MISMATCH: line 31:9: Cannot cast varbinary to varchar(256)
```

The objective is to get a unique identifier for each row of data that can be compared on each data load to know if the record was changed.

I tried concatenating the rows using the concatenation operator.
The concatenation operator requires that all data types are identical, so I cast the non-string data types.
The concatenation operator also nullifies the whole row in case one of the values is null, so I used coalesce. And I cast the checksum to be able to insert it in the table (I need to cast it to integer or varchar).

Comment: The Redshift Spectrum error indicates that the argument to checksum() is not of the correct data type.  What are the datatypes of TITLE and COUNTRY in the source files on S3 and in the data catalog?  You may just need to cast the result of the concatenation to varchar to resolve (or at least get closer to the root issue).

Comment: TITLE and COUNTRY are VARCHARs. Something I forgot to mention is that trying the select statement alone (without the insert into part) in Athena gets an output, with the CHECKSUM column in hexadecimal format. Trying the select statement in DBeaver gives the same error as the insert statement.